# Passing to the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ to show that $l(I) \le m^{*}(I)$ for an interval $I = [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, real-numbers

I am reading a measure theory book and the author wants to show that the length of an interval $I = [a,b]$ is less than or equal to its outer measure, i.e., we want to show that
$$l(I) \le m^{*}(I).$$
The proof proceeds by saying it is sufficient to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$,
$$l(I) \le m^*(I) + \epsilon,$$
and then obtaining the required inequality by passing to the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

I don't understand why it is sufficient and why showing that $l(I) \le m^*(I) + \epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0 \implies l(I) \le m^{*}(I)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $l(I)>m^*(I)$ and let $\varepsilon=\frac{l(I)-m^*(I)}2$. Then $l(I)>m^*(I)+\varepsilon$ , but we are assuming that $(\forall\varepsilon>0):l(I)\leqslant m^*(I)+\varepsilon$.